# Unable to Pass Django Context Data to HTML View

Tags: python, django

Can anybody please tell me how can I pass context data to view? I get nothing in HTML page.

views.py

```py
def cart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect('index')

    else:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            # Recieve local storage product in post_id varibale
            post_id = request.GET.get('get_cart')
            cat_product = Product.objects.filter(id=.11)
            if post_id is not None:
            # Fomrat and remove { } and " from  post_id string
                post_id = post_id.replace('{','')
                post_id = post_id.replace('}','')
                post_id = post_id.replace('"','')
                print("The Id is", post_id )
            # Find ':' in string and get the value of id in cart_prod_index
                index =0
                while index < len(post_id):
                    index = post_id.find(':', index)
                    if index == -1:
                        break
                    local_storage_prod_id = post_id[index-1]

                    # '|' operator is used to append the queryset result

                    cat_product = cat_product | Product.objects.filter(id=local_storage_prod_id)
                
                    index+=2
            print(cat_product)
            return render(request, "cart.html" ,{"x":cat_product,})
```

In cart.html

```html
{% for search in x %}
  {{search.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I get my query set in HTML page?

Comment: are you sure this is correct? `Product.objects.filter(id=.11)` (it's quite unusual to use a float value as the db id)

Comment: most likely answer is that neither of your queries return any results... what does `print(cat_product)` show?

Comment: I'm also not sure if python interpreter is not creating tuple here:
`cat_product,`
So the context param should be just:
`{"x":cat_product}`

Comment: Print(cat_product) shows the queryset of my items

Comment: Product.objects.filter(id=.11) it is currect. It gives the black query set. With help of this I can append my query set using | operator

Comment: 'print(cat_product)' print following query set '<QuerySet [<Product: Men Black T shirt>, <Product: White T Shirt>, <Product: Black Lady T Shirt>, <Product: Tomato>, <Product: White Ladies T Shirt>, <Product: Capsicum>, <Product: Nice Girl Kurti>]>'